# If two same fields exists insert else update

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say i have `two` fields `a` and `b`.

Now let's say i want to write a query which would update if `a = 100 AND b = 120` else it would create new field.

Also `a` and `b` have to be unique to each other, what i mean is that it can be two `a` equals to `100` or two `b` equals to `200`, but there can't be more fields like

`a` = `100` and `b` = `120`, i hope you get what i mean.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really can't understand what you're asking here...

Comment: fields are different to rows.. can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean with _"else it would create new field"_? Do you want to update a row if condition is met and add a new row if not? Well, this is not possible with one query for what I know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `(a,b)` combination, you can use the [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax for this functionality. Examples:

```
INSERT INTO TableX
  ( a, b, c, d, e)
VALUES
  ( 100, 200, 1, 2, 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  c = VALUES(c)
, d = VALUES(d)
, e = VALUES(e)

INSERT INTO TableX
  ( a, b, c, d, e)
VALUES
  ( 100, 200, 1, 7, 20)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  c = c + 1
, d = d + 1
, e = e + 1
```