# SQL `update` if combination of keys exists in row - else create new row

Tags: mysql, sql

First of, I've searched this topic here and elsewhere online, and found numorous articles and answers, but none of which did this...

I have a `table` with ratings, and you should be able to update your rating, but not create a new row.

My table contains: `productId`, `rating`, `userId`

If a row with `productId` and `userId` exists, then update `rating`. Else create new row.

How do I do this?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` Have you searched for that?

Comment: Yes, but it's not a duplicate key. The userId could rate other productIds and other users could too rate...

Comment: Two columns can together act as primary key, so then it will be a duplicate key

Comment: With a unique (or primary key) constraint on `(userID, productID)`, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` construct would work fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If two same fields exists insert else update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136695/if-two-same-fields-exists-insert-else-update)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add a `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE tableX
  ADD CONSTRAINT productId_userId_UQ
    UNIQUE (productId, userId) ;
```

Then you can use the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` construction:

```
INSERT INTO tableX
  (productId, userId, rating)
VALUES
  (101, 42, 5),
  (102, 42, 6),
  (103, 42, 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  rating = VALUES(rating) ;
```

See the **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e524/1)**

Comment: This does not allow me to rate more than one product... It only updates the rating on the first product...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something or need to provide more information. Your program has to perform a SQL query (a SELECT statement) to find out if the table contains a row with a given productId and userId, then perform a UPDATE statement to update the rating, otherwise perform a INSERT to insert the new row. These are separate steps unless you group them into a stored procedure.

Comment: How do I make these seperate steps with one call from PHP? Can you guide me to an example or show me?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `REPLACE INTO` query.

```
REPLACE INTO table (productId, userId, rating) VALUES ('product id', 'user id', 'rating');
```

`REPLACE INTO` is like a normal insert, except if it finds a row already in the table with the same unique key it will delete that row before inserting.

Comment: Your unique key should be a composite key of product_id and user_id, in this case it also happens to be your primary key. When the query runs, if it finds an existing product_id and user_id combination it will delete that row then perform the insert.

Comment: `REPLACE` has several disdvantages. Read this: [“INSERT IGNORE” vs “INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)